# yWorks UML Doclet Netbeans Java

Tags: java, netbeans, uml

I have followed the instructions from this page [yWorks UML Doclet](http://www.yworks.com/en/downloads.html#yDoc) to generate UML Diagrams in netbeans. I have successfully installed and javadoc is generated but there are no **UML Diagrams** in the javadoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate Javadoc (Project > Right Click >  Generate Javadoc) and you will see UML diagrams there in the javadoc of your project (browser). but before that you have to add yworks related code into javadoc

[image]

In the box: Additional Javadoc options, enter the following text (replace the path to yDoc corresponding to your installation):

```
-docletpath /opt/umldoclet/lib/ydoc.jar -resourcepath /opt/umldoclet/resources -doclet ydoc.doclets.YStandard -umlautogen
```

then generate UML diagram as below

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work I get `javadoc: error - Cannot find doclet class ydoc.doclets.YStandard`

Comment: never mind replacing the “ by " made it work, problem from following http://imagine.kicbak.com/blog/?p=58 gave bad chars